# How to throw an exception when a user is not found in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying these code and I wanna throw an exception when user is not found. How can I do that?

Thank you so much.

When user not found I am getting this error;

NotFoundHttpException in Handler.php line 102:
No query results for model [App\User]

```
public function showProfile($username)
{   
   return $user = User::where('username', $username)->firstOrFail();
}
```

Comment: So, uh, it's currently doing what you want?

Comment: I am gonna throw an exception when user is not found in query like 'user is not found' page.

Comment: Seems like you want to _catch_ an exception. Wrap the code that throws an exception in a try/catch. In the catch block you can log the error (if you want to) - and return a "pretty error template" to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allow Laravel to handle when users are not found try this:

```
public function showProfile($username)
{   
   $user = User::where('username', $username)->first();
   if ($user === null) {
       // do something, like return a view to an error page
       return "User Not Found!"
   }
   // Code to execute if a user is found.
   return $user;
}
```

If you use `->firstOrFail()`, it will throw an exception which will be returned back to your user as an Internal Error (when in production mode).

It would be better to user `->first()` as this will just return `null` if no records are found, allowing you to handle the issue yourself.

Alternatively you can use a try catch block like so:

```
public function showProfile($username)
{   
   $user = User::where('username', $username)->first();

   try {
       $user = User::firstOrFail($user->id);
       return $user;
   } catch (Exception $e) {
      return "User Not Found";
   }
}
```

Comment: I think you right. Your way is better. Thank you so much :+1

Comment: You know you can physically +1 on the question lol by pressing the up arrow on the question :-)